# Can i avoid 2 lookups by using _G?

Tags: lua, scope

I've read that if you use some functions like `table.insert`, lua will first try to lookup the variable in the local scope, then in global scope. Can i bypass the local lookup by using `_G.table.insert` instead?

Here's the output of luac -l:
without _G

```
main <main.lua:0,0> (7 instructions at 0x55581ae50c60)
0+ params, 4 slots, 1 upvalue, 1 local, 3 constants, 0 functions
    1   [1] NEWTABLE    0 0 0
    2   [2] GETTABUP    1 0 -1  ; _ENV "table"
    3   [2] GETTABLE    1 1 -2  ; "insert"
    4   [2] MOVE        2 0
    5   [2] LOADK       3 -3    ; 5
    6   [2] CALL        1 3 1
    7   [2] RETURN      0 1
```

with _G

```
main <main.lua:0,0> (8 instructions at 0x5562b3d6dc60)
0+ params, 4 slots, 1 upvalue, 1 local, 4 constants, 0 functions
    1   [1] NEWTABLE    0 0 0
    2   [2] GETTABUP    1 0 -1  ; _ENV "_G"
    3   [2] GETTABLE    1 1 -2  ; "table"
    4   [2] GETTABLE    1 1 -3  ; "insert"
    5   [2] MOVE        2 0
    6   [2] LOADK       3 -4    ; 5
    7   [2] CALL        1 3 1
    8   [2] RETURN      0 1
```

I'm not sure what the numbers mean.

Comment: Check the output of `luac -l` on a test script.

Comment: @lhf it tells me it gets `table` from `_ENV`, but it also says that for `_G`. I read that it makes more lookups when calling a global variable, so i thought if `_G` is reserved, then it would only make one lookup. Is this correct?

Comment: `_G` is not reserved. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: nothing, nevermind then. I was basing the 2 lookups thing off of [the love2d optimising page](https://love2d.org/wiki/Optimising), there they said it's bad to have 2 lookups. I've also read that `_G` is resrved by the language on SO.

Comment: See also [Lua Performance Tips](https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

`_G` is not reserved and it's probably even worse with it, as i can see from the compiler output. I think doing it with `_G` is even slower.